# Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href*='play.google.com']"}

Tags: selenium-webdriver, findelement

[image]I am trying to recreate a script done in my online class thru Udemy.  There are 2 findElement commands and it appears to run the first one but i get the above error message when it looks for it.  the code is exactly the same in the video but his runs to completion and mine gets the error message. Any and all help would be appreciated.  Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried checking what the findElement returns before you initiate the click method?

Comment: No i have not. I am sort of new with this so i don't know how to find out what the findElement returns.

Comment: Can you at least share what error you are getting so we can better understand what the problem is?

Comment: Also, please, post the code as text snippet, and not image.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href*='play.google.com']"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)